# collect value only from the text input that have been changed

Tags: jquery, forms, textinput

I have a html page that after ajax call show a lot of data rows, in every row i have input text with different value, the user can edit this text input and then press a button to do some calculate action.

How can I collect with javascript(jQuery) only this values that have been changed, and send them to php script. I search a simple way, not to save all big array of old values then compare with new values, Is there such solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function to keep a copy of their original values, then compare that against their values when submitting to make sure that only changed values are submitted.

```
var inputs = $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    $(this).data('original', this.value);
});

$('#form').submit(function(){
    inputs.each(function() {
        if ($(this).data('original') !== this.value) {
            // Do something for the changed value
        } else {
            // And something else for the rest.
        }
    });
});
```

See a demo of this here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/twCE9/

Comment: how can i save also the id for each input ?

Comment: @Haim In the `data` object you use in the ajax function, you can use `this.id` to get the `id` of the current element, like `this.value` I used above.

Comment: i mean i want to save 2 values per element one is the id and another is a value, what is the syntax to save 2 pairs (array) in data function

Comment: @Haim You do something like `$.post(url, {value: this.value, id: this.id}, success)`. See the jQuery documentation for those functions for more details

Comment: thanks , its work i use $(this).data('original', this.value, 'id', this.id); to save also the id

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onChange event of the input field and collect the info in some hidden field or global array field for this.

Answer (score 1):

You bind to the change event for each data input and either store those name-value pairs in a global array or into hidden form fields.

An alternative would be to add a "changed" class to each field which was edited. Then when they submit the form, you could either create a new form with just those elements of class changed or remove the other elements from your form containing all the text inputs.

```
<input type="text" class="data_input" name="name1" value="value1" />
<input type="text" class="data_input" name="name2" value="value2" />
...
<input type="text" class="data_input" name="nameX" value="valueX" />
```

Then in your JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".data_input").change(function() {
        $(this).addClass('changed');
    });
```

Or if you're willing to use a global array:

```
var changedArr = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".data_input").change(function() {
        changedArr.push({'name': $(this).attr('name'), 'value': $(this).val()});
    });
```

Comment: i  forgot to say that this rows with the text input build with ajax call

Comment: Using `this.value` and `this.name` will save you from creating a new jQuery object inside the anonymous function you pass to the event handler.