# Getting values of textfields on page

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, forms

Lets just say that I have some (many many many) text fields on a page... and i enter a new value in one of them, then click a button... How can I update the database with just that new value? Or, if it would be easier... How can I update all of those textfields to the database?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are the text field names the same as the field names in the database?

Comment: @matt_abury, they can be. I'm sure that won't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), to store the first state ,

when you want to post it, post only the textbox that has been changed .

see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067180/collect-value-only-from-the-text-input-that-have-been-changed)

Comment: I don't think is has anything to do with jquery(yet)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql = "UPDATE table_name SET";
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if($key != 'submit'){
        $sql .= " " . $key . " = '" . $value . "'";
    }
}
$sql = " WHERE ......";
?>
```

This will generate the sql statement for you. You just need to add in security and then the execution.

Comment: So, all I have to do is just add a form, then upon Submitting it, your above script will just update the whole thing? Awesome :) Will give it a go.

Comment: Don't forget to validate the input fields though by checking the $value variable in the loop to make sure they are not entering something they shouldn't.

Comment: I have edited the loop to make sure you ignore the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

**To update everything:**

You can organize your inputs like this (1,2,3,4 - are record id's in database):

```
<input type="text" name="info[1]" value="blabla">
<input type="text" name="info[2]" value="blabla">
<input type="text" name="info[3]" value="blabla">
<input type="text" name="info[4]" value="blabla">
<!-- ... -->
```

Then, in your PHP script:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['info'] as $id=>$data){
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET data = '".mysql_escape_string($data)."' WHERE id = ".intval($id));
}
?>
```

This way there will be one UPDATE statement for every record

**To update only those that changed:**

You can use javascript's onChange() event to see what fields were changed and submit only those. Just be carefull, if a user has javascript disabled, he well never be able to change any record.

Comment: Thank you :) How would I be able to just update the one that was just changed?, I only need them to change one thing at a time

Comment: And that is why using java script in this scenario is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

identify textfield values: every textfield is supposed to have a "name" attribute:

```
 <input type="text" name="firstName" value="please enter your first name"/>
```

you can the access the value of the textfield "foo" with $_POST["foo"]
To know if the field was changed you must compare it with the default value.

```
if($_POST["firstName"]!="please enter your first name"){
   /*do databse update*/
}
```

How exactly you do the database update depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see this, it has two approaches

1 - After you clicks the save button, you collect all the values to an array (Using javascrip) and pass that array (As a comma separated list or something) to the server. there inside a transaction block you delete all the existing values from the table and insert the new values.

2 - But If you have many, many text values, have a javascript to identify the changing text boxes only.

simple procedure would be,

- select a text field

  get its value to a variable

  when user does a change to the text
  field always compare with the
  original value

  If the value changed, flag that text
  box

  when user clicks 'save' get only the
  changed value fields

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 0):

You can do all that using javascript/jquery:

```
  <div id="inputs">
   <input type="text" id="in1" />
   <input type="text" id="in2" />
   <input type="text" id="in3" />
   ...
  </div> 

  $(function() {
     $('#inputs input').each(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'your script url'
          data: { input : $(this).val(), id : $(this).attr('id') },
          success: function(result) {
            //do whatever you want with result
          }
        });
     });
  });
```

i didnt test this but i'm sure this would work. If you have experience with javascript/jquery its pretty easy to update database based on the fields that are filled out. You can test on client side (javascript) if any of the field is empty.

forgot to add: PHP side:

```
     function somescript() {
      if (!isset($_POST['input']) || ! isset($_POST['id']) {
         //do something to handle post not being set
      }

      $in = sanitize($_POST['input']);
      $id = sanitize($_POST['id']);
      //sanitize is a function that you should write to clean the user input

      //have a query and pass in the $in and $id
      //id can be used in your where statement
     }
```